# Dynamically adding children of arbitrary types to React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using [react-art](https://github.com/reactjs/react-art) to make a little app where a number of different shapes can be added/removed at runtime by the user.

The way I'm imagining doing it is outlined below. *Note: ES6 syntax.*

Top-level canvas, with a list of objects representing the shapes and their current states (e.g. position):

```
class Canvas extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props); // includes list of shapes
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Surface>
        // my shapes here
      </Surface>
    );
  }
}
```

A number of React components for different shapes:

```
class SimpleShape extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props); // includes e.g. position of shape
  }

  render() {
    <Circle />
    <Rectangle />
  }
}
```

I'm thinking of doing something like this in the `Canvas` component to render the shapes:

```
render() {
  return (
    <Surface>
      this.props.shapes.map(function(shape) {
        return React.createElement(shape.component, shape.props);
      });
    </Surface>
  );
}
```

I've been unable to find an example of a situation where the number, and type, of children for a React component is dynamic. It almost feels like I'm fighting against the React way by passing in child components as props, but I can't think of another way of doing it.

My question is, what is the idiomatic React way of doing this? Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

<sub><sub>I hope this isn't too much of a discussion question!</sub></sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your way is React's way, based in this [React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children):

```
  render: function() {
    var results = this.props.results;
    return (
      <ol>
        {results.map(function(result) {
           return <li key={result.id}>{result.text}</li>;
        })}
      </ol>
    );
  }
```

For this you have to keyed your child elements, like vkurchatkin says:

> When React reconciles the keyed children, it will ensure that any child with key will be reordered (instead of clobbered) or destroyed (instead of reused).